# getting error while deploying the react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

WARNING in src\App.js
Line 69:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getNewPins'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: You can just ignore that warning if you do not intend to add a dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

This warning generally means that there is some variable that the useEffect function is using and whenever that variable changes useEffect should run again. You should then ideally include that variable in the useEffect dependency array
This has a more elaborate description:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects